# Changing the colour of Beamer \titlepage using a .sty file

Tags: beamer, color, titles

I've been looking for an answer everywhere to this, but so far, nothing seems to have worked. What I would like to do is change the background colour and font colour of the `\titlepage` command, but to do so within the custom `.sty` file I have generated, i.e. I don't want to have to specify the change in colours within the `.tex` file.

The (hopefully as basic as possible) `.tex` file outline is (some lines are commented out to ensure the example can be run without extra files - if you wish to add your own files to see it working, feel free!):

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Oxford}

    \usepackage{color,graphicx}
    \usepackage{epsfig} % Modifies table/figure captions
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

    \author{Author Name}
    \title{Presentation Title}
    \institute{Institute Name}

    \date{}

    \begin{document}
       \begin{frame}[plain]
          \titlepage
       \end{frame}

       \begin{frame}
          \frametitle{Outline}
          \tableofcontents
       \end{frame}

       \section{Example Section}
       \begin{frame}
          \frametitle{Example Frame}
       \end{frame}

       \section{Second Example}
       \begin{frame}
          \frametitle{Example Frame With a Block}
          \begin{block}{Test Block}
             Testing the block colour here\ldots{}
          \end{block}
       \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

The associated `beamerthemeOxford.sty` file is thus:

```
    \DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
    \ProcessOptionsBeamer
    \mode<presentation>

    \useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
    \useinnertheme{circles}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}

    % Define the colours that are to be used in the presentation
    \definecolor{oxfordblue}{RGB}{0,33,71}          % Oxford Blue
    \definecolor{oxfordgold}{cmyk}{0,0.21,0.60,0.30}    % Oxford Gold

    % Set which colours apply to which structures
    \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=oxfordblue}
    \setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=oxfordblue}
    \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=oxfordblue}
    \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=oxfordblue}
    \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=oxfordblue,fg=white}

    % Define the headline and titlebar
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}
    {
       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1\paperwidth,left]{section in head/foot}
       \vskip2pt
       \insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}
       \vskip2pt
       \end{beamercolorbox}
    }

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} 
    % \pgfdeclareimage[height=1.1cm]{logo}{logo_file}
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\paperwidth}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\paperheight}
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
    {
       \vskip-1pt
       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1\paperwidth,left]{section in head/foot}
          \vskip-15pt
          \begin{tikzpicture}
             \shade[left color=white,right  color=oxfordblue] (0,0) rectangle +(11,0.02);
          \end{tikzpicture}
          \vskip-2pt
          \hskip10pt\strut\insertframetitle\strut\\
       \end{beamercolorbox} 
       \begin{textblock}{0.2}[0.5,0.5](0.99,0.07)
          % \pgfuseimage{logo}
       \end{textblock} 
    }

    % Adapt other segments of code
    \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

    % Ensures navigation circles are displayed
    \usepackage{remreset}
    \makeatletter
    \@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
    \makeatother
    \setcounter{subsection}{1}

    % Reformat Title Page to our own specifications
    \setbeamertemplate{title page}
    {
    \setbeamercolor*{background canvas}{fg=oxfordblue,bg=oxfordblue}
    %   \setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=oxfordblue,bg=oxfordblue}
    %   \setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
       \begin{columns}
          \column{0.7\textwidth}
          \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
          \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty
          \else
             \vskip2ex
             \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle
          \fi
          \ifx\insertauthor\@empty
          \else
             \vskip2ex
             \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
          \fi
          \ifx\insertdate\@empty
          \else
             \vskip2ex
             \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate%
          \fi
          \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty
          \else
             \vskip2ex
             \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute%
          \fi
          \vfill
          \column{0.3\textwidth}
          % \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic1}\\
          \vskip5pt
          % \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic2}\\
          \vskip5pt
          % \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic3}
       \end{columns}
    }

    \mode
    <all>
```

There were various other hacks that I tried, but they all came to nothing and were inelegant kludges. In either case, the background colour of the title page remains resolutely white, whereas I want to have the background as `oxfordblue` and the font as `white`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't compile your MWE. After commenting the `\includegraphics` lines of `beamerthemeOxford.sty`, compilation fails with `! Missing $ inserted.  <inserted text>  $  l.22        \end{frame}`...

Comment: There's also a `logo_file` earlier in the code - I've now commented it out in the example so it should work straight from the box.

Comment: `epsfig` is deprecated and ought not be used. Declaring the graphics extensions is unnecessary and potentially problematic. Loading `color` and `graphicx` is unnecessary.

Comment: @user94293 Why set a bounty on a question which has already received a satisfactory answer? It isn't clear what more you'd want done (although there is now a TikZ-based answer, but there's no indication you want an answer of that kind...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question! And to be honest, I do not know the answer, but I use a workaround in my own style files. In the `.sty` file, I define a wrapper macro for the titlepage similar to

```
      \newcommand{\insertoxfordtitle}{%
        \setbeamercolor*{background canvas}{fg=oxfordblue,bg=oxfordblue}
        \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
      \end{frame}
      \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=oxfordblue,bg=white}
    }
```

In the `.tex` file I replace the title frame by `\insertoxfordtitle`.

Relevant changes to the `.sty` file:

```
    % Reformat Title Page to our own specifications
    \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}
    \setbeamercolor*{subtitle}{fg=white}
    \setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}

      \newcommand{\insertoxfordtitle}{%
        \setbeamercolor*{background canvas}{fg=oxfordblue,bg=oxfordblue}
        \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
      \end{frame}
      \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=oxfordblue,bg=white}
    }

   \setbeamertemplate{title page}{
       \begin{columns}
          \column{0.7\textwidth}
          \usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle
          \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty
          \else
             \vskip2ex
             \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle
          \fi
          \ifx\insertauthor\@empty
          \else
             \vskip2ex
             \usebeamerfont{author}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author}\insertauthor
          \fi
          \ifx\insertdate\@empty
          \else
             \vskip2ex
             \usebeamerfont{date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{date}\insertdate%
          \fi
          \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty
          \else
             \vskip2ex
             \usebeamerfont{institute}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institut}\insertinstitute%
          \fi
          \vfill
          \column{0.3\textwidth}
          % \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic1}\\
          \vskip5pt
          % \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic2}\\
          \vskip5pt
          % \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pic3}
       \end{columns}
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How to do the same, but in a *.sty file as originally asked?

Comment: @user94293 I am afraid, I do not understand your comment. Everything I wrote in my answer happens in a .sty file.

Comment: This solution requires to use `\insertoxfordtitle` for producing the title page.  The usual `\frame{\titlepage}` or `\maketitle` do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

As the example already loads the `tikz` one could just as well use it to draw a coloured rectangle on the title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{oxfordblue}{RGB}{0,33,71} 

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[at=(current page.center),fill=oxfordblue, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    However you would normally define your title page
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

To use this solution from within a `.sty` file, just copy everything within `\setbeamertemplate{title page}{...}` there.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to create a dedicated page style that will be used for the title page.

In the file below, the dedicated page style is called `navigation@titlepage`.  You can add there any modification you want to apply to the title page.  As an illustration, we add a blue background as asked by the OP.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{Author Name}
\title{Presentation Title}
\institute{Institute Name}
\date{}

\definecolor{oxfordblue}{RGB}{0,33,71} 


\makeatletter
\def\ps@navigation@titlepage{%
  % Add here all the changes you want to apply to the title page
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=oxfordblue}%  blue background
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{\thispagestyle{navigation@titlepage}}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Example Section}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example Frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Second Example}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example Frame With a Block}
  \begin{block}{Test Block}
    Testing the block colour here\ldots{}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]